# callback for loop values of List Item's (Kivy & KivyMD)

Tags: python, function, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

Here I have a loop that looks for keys & values from a JSON List

Currently, the view of the KivyMD List is correct but I want to pass onto the correct key onto print instead of having the **last key** from JSON printed out.

```
ScrollView:
    MDList:
        id: container
```

```
   def on_start(self):
        for (self.k, v) in self.data.items():  

            item = TwoLineAvatarListItem(text=str(self.k),secondary_text=str(v["NAME"]),on_release=self.show_data)
            image = ImageLeftWidget(source=v["Image"])
            item.add_widget(image)
            self.root.ids.container.add_widget(item)

    def show_data(self,obj):
        print(self.k)
```

[image]

The **value:** E101a is always printed

To summarize i want to look at the "container values" separate

Comment: your code doesn't run as it is. what libraries are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jonas! I have solved it with this:

```
on_release=lambda x, value_for_pass=value: self.passValue(value_for_pass)
```

In a loop like this:

.py file:

```
# (...)
class AllClientsScreen(Screen):
    
    def on_enter(self):
        self.show_clients()

    def show_clients(self):
        for i in range(10):
            client_id = i
            name = "Roger" + str(client_id) + " id: " + str(client_id)
            last_name = "Rabbit" + str(client_id)
            phone = "555" + str(client_id)
            email = "roger" + str(client_id) + "@rabbit.com"
            item = ThreeLineListItem(
            text = name + " " + last_name,
            secondary_text = phone,
            tertiary_text = email,
            on_release=lambda x, value_for_pass=name: self.passValue(value_for_pass)
            )
                
            self.ids.container.add_widget(item)
    
    def passValue(self, *args):
        args_str = ','.join(map(str,args))
        screen2 = self.manager.get_screen ('oneclient')
        screen2.ids.client_id.text = args_str
        self.manager.current = 'oneclient'
        print(args)
```

.kv file:

```
#:import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition

ScreenManager:
    transition: NoTransition()
    MenuScreen:
    AllClientsScreen:
    OneClientScreen:

<MenuScreen>:
    name: 'menu'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'All Clients'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'allclients'
    
<AllClientsScreen>:
    name: 'allclients'
    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            id: container
            padding: dp(20)

    MDLabel:
        id: clientsdata
        text: 'All Clients'
        halign: 'center'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Menu'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y':0.4}
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'menu'

<OneClientScreen>:
    name: 'oneclient'
    MDLabel:
        id: client_id
        text: 'Cliente'
        halign: 'center'
    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            id: container
            padding: dp(40)
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Menu'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y':0.4}
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'menu'
```

I have just posted the essential parts of the codes, if you have any doubts or get succed, please let me know.
Have a nice development!